# Autodesk Platform Services: Upload file with comma "," in file name returns no URN

Tags: autodesk-forge

After uploading a file with a comma "," in the file name, the requested document URN is always null. Thus, the file is re-uploaded every time I try to open the file. Is this a bug or is there a naming convention forbidding commas in file names?

Comment: Let me check with our engineers, but what is the reasoning for using a comma instead of a dash for example.

Comment: Toni, any chance you can provide us with the URN of the file send it over to aps.help@autodesk.com We are not able to replicate the issue with a Revit model for example, the translation happens with a file with name test,s.rvt for example.

Comment: @Jaime Rosales Thanks for your reply. The reasoning is that customers can upload whatever file they want, and we don't want to edit the filename before uploading. I will send the URN to aps.help@autodesk.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in my code. I splitted the response using commas, thus when the response contained a file name with a comma, the splitting was different which caused the problem.
Thanks to @Jaime Rosales for supporting!